# MySQL trigger: Compare value in another table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have the following trigger (generated using PHP via mysqli)...

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS post_queue_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER post_queue_insert AFTER INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.post_type != 'revision' AND NEW.post_status != 'auto-draft') THEN
        INSERT INTO event_queue (action_id, action_do, action_key, action_value, action_event, action_timestamp, sync_complete, SITE_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID, 'post', NEW.post_type, NEW.post_status, 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), 0, 1);
    END IF;
END;
```

What I can't figure out is how to check if the 'post_type' value exists in another table and if it doesn't then insert it.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS post_queue_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER post_queue_insert AFTER INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE found_it INT;
    IF (NEW.post_type != 'revision' AND NEW.post_status != 'auto-draft') THEN
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_it FROM some_other_table
        WHERE post_type = NEW.post_type;
        IF found_it = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO event_queue (action_id, action_do, action_key, action_value, action_event, action_timestamp, sync_complete, SITE_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID, 'post', NEW.post_type, NEW.post_status, 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), 0, 1);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

If found_it = 0, then the row does not contain a value matching NEW.post_type.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS post_queue_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER post_queue_insert AFTER INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF  ( NEW.post_type != 'revision' 
      AND NEW.post_status != 'auto-draft'
      AND NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM other_table
            WHERE post_type = NEW.post_type
          )
        )
    THEN
        INSERT INTO event_queue (action_id, action_do, action_key, action_value, action_event, action_timestamp, sync_complete, SITE_ID) 
        VALUES (NEW.ID, 'post', NEW.post_type, NEW.post_status, 'insert', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), 0, 1);
    END IF;
END;
```